# Shortest path without any segment line and topography

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shortest-path

I would like to create the shortest lines between destinations. I do not have any segment lines, so I can not use the network analyst tool. I tried another command, cost path, however, I have issues with this tool. My working area is flat (water), so the height is not a really an effective factor. But I still tried to run this command. You can see the steps one by one below.
I guess because of the cost backlink I live this kind of the shortest path. The path is wavy and does all these zigzags so it is not really the shortest path.

Is there any other tool I can use which will help me to find the shortest route depending on the edges/boundaries in the images (in the first image you can see the boundaries on the topography)?

[image: maps -step by step]

Comment: Your cost surface should be single number, i.e. no colours. Make the rest no data or something very big.

Comment: So I should make all moveable spaces with the same number and the rest big? How can I make these changes, should I convert the data to shp first? And should I change the height map like this?

Comment: Learn how Con() in spatial analyst works.